# Twitter Style auto suggest username feature

Tags: jquery, twitter, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement twitter style auto-suggest username feature which would be enabled when typed "@" sign. I found something that can be implemented using jquery.ui. But, seems it won't allow multiple usernames at a time.

I can generate a JSON output with a list of required usernames but struggling to figure out how to catch the @ sign anywhere in the text. I am also looking to display user's image, location in auto suggest list.

Also, I found http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories which allows to display list category-wise. How can I integrate this with multiple username feature.

Sample text: **Hello @username1 @username2. Dummy Text1 test2 @username3**.

I don't have much experience in jquery. Can any one please guide me.

Comment: well, for starters, you could use regex to replace the usernames with meaningful html.  e.g. `"Hello @username1 @username2".replace(/@(\w*)/g,"user:$1")` or what not, which results in the string `"Hello user:username1 user:username2"`

Comment: It seems simple to implement but somehow I am not able to do it.

Comment: can you provide us with some code? What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/bSbKu/ I found something which solved multiple @ tagging issue, but how can I insert html in suggestion list?

Comment: made it work: http://jsfiddle.net/bSbKu/6/

Comment: In above code, I am trying to replace username but it acts weirdly if I have a email address in string. E.g.,: *This is a email abc@gmail.com hello test123 @gma*  Now when I select a username starting with "gma", the [at]gma from email address is replaced but not the last [at]gma. Can you let me know how do I detect the current @ and replace and update username accordingly.